# Is ElasticSearch memory indexes are fast?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 indexes in Elastic search one is running on default store type other one is running on memory store type. I have inserted 100,000 documents to each of these two indexes the default storage index is 1 second faster than the ram index. why is that ?

and on searching also the default index is fast.

my ES server is running on an SSD.
can someone please explain me why the in memory index is slower than the one store on the SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to monitor what's going on with your JVM and system memory during your load-test to really understand what's going on.

The `memory` index option can work against the OS memory manager.  It also can increase garbage-collection pauses by causing the JVM to work harder to free up space.

The `default` option (`mmapfs` on 64-bit Linux systems) lets the OS manage the caching/swapping memory pages in a more efficient way.

1 second is a lot of added latency for a query against a small index.  If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say your `memory` index isn't 100% resident in physical memory, and the OS is therefore having to swap unnecessarily big pages from virtual->physical before a query can complete.

This article goes into more detail (from a Solr context, but the underlying Lucene implementation is the same):  http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html

Try bumping up the memory on your system, or testing against a smaller number of docs to see if the discrepancy is still there.

Comment: Hi, I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have 16 gigs of DDR3 Ram. I am not running anything else in the background also. I haven't changed the default JVM heap size of Elastic-Search, should I ?. because 100K of very small documents won't fill up the default ES heap size , would it?

Comment: HI again, The article u linked is very good. I think I got the answer for my Problem, Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is disable swap completely on your system. 
You can try:

```
#sudo swapoff -a
```

Or edit your /etc/fstab

You can also prevent JVM from being swapped by the OS. In elasticsearch.yml :

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```